# How do I assign SharePoint and Power Apps licenses to the guest users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, licensing, guest-access

We are trying to invite guest users so that they can use our Power Apps connected to SharePoint. The problem is that I don't understand how to assign a license to guest users. I have read that it's possible, but when we actually try to do it, there is no options anywhere to do it. Does anyone know how it is supposed to work?

[image]

[image]

I will be really grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, we can't assign licenses to the gest users via the Microsoft 365 admin portal. We have to do it via the A[zure AD Admin Portal](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2067268).

How to assign licenses to a guest user: [MS Docs Article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/assign-licenses-to-users?view=o365-worldwide#assign-a-license-to-a-guest-user)

- Go to the [Azure Active Directory admin portal](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2067268)
- In the navigation pane, select Users.
- On the Users | All Users (Preview) page, select Add filters.
- In the Pick a field menu, choose User type, then select Apply.
- In the next menu, select Guest.
- In the list of results, select the user who needs a license.
- Under Manage, select Licenses.
- Select Assignments.
- On the Update license assignments page, select the product you want to assign a license for.
  On the right, clear the check boxes for any services you don't want the guest user to have access to.
  Select Save.

[image]

[image]

[image]